# AngularJS routed page refresh never loads

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I'm trying to use AngularJS in a salesforce local hybrid android app, and while a simple test of the angular code works in firefox, when I run it in the Android emulator it loads for a fraction of a second and is replaced with a blank screen.

I've noticed that refreshing the page after routing ( going to `[URL]/index.html#/` after the first page load ) ends up with an eternal 'ajax loading' spinner. I suspect this might be the root of my problem. My routing code looks like this:

```
var contactlistModule = angular.module("AugmentedContactList", ['ngRoute']);

contactlistModule.controller(ContactlistController);

contactlistModule.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        controller: 'ContactlistController',
        templateUrl: 'viewparts/contactlistview.html'
    }).when('/contact', {
        controller: 'ContactController',
        templateUrl: 'viewparts/contact.html'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
}]);
```

Why does this refreshing error happen? Shouldn't going to `index.html` have the same effect as `index.html#/` ?

Comment: it should be index.html/#

Answer (score 1):

I guess going to `index.html` without enabling `html5Mode` won't work as you expect.

You can enable it by injecting `$locationProvider` and adding this line to your config:

`$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`

However, be aware that to enable html5 mode you will need to configure your server to return `index.html` (or whatever your main page is) on every URL request.

See also:

[$locationProvider docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/%24location)